# SQL Server Import from XLS cant convert Double to int/bit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I exported an sql database out as an excel file so that I could send it off to be edited by hand. I used the `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` then the `SQL Server Import and Export Wizard` to do so. Now the edits are finished and when I go to reimport the file I get

```
Found 7 unknown column type conversion(s)
You are only allowed to save the package
```

And it wont let me run the import. It seems to me as though the export to excel converted all `int` and `bit` datatypes into `Double` datatypes and It doesn't know how to convert back. I did a bit of googling and I found the `SSIS10ToMSSQL.XML` file (which appears to control how the conversion takes place), but I don't know how I should edit it to tell the wizard how to convert correctly.

Any input on this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After **WAYYYYYY** to many hours spent trying other formats and settings, I just bit the bullet and wrote a console app to read in a csv (exported from excel) and run the necessary SQL on the database.